# Proving convergence of infinite series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to prove that for $x\in[0,\pi]$

$$
\frac{\sin (x)}{3} - \frac{\sin (3x)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} - \frac{\sin (5x)}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} - \frac{\sin (7x)}{5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9} \cdots = \frac{\pi}{8} \sin^2 (x)
$$

and determine if the series converges uniformly, pointwise, and/or in $L^2$.

I've identified that we can write it as

$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{3} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty - \frac{\sin((2n+3)x)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)(2n+5)}
$$

which looks an awful lot like the Fourier series of $
f(x)=\frac{\pi}{8} \sin^2(x).
$

Indeed, if we pretend $f(x)$ is odd (even though it's even), and runs on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, we get the right coefficients. We have

$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \sin(kx)
$$

where

$$
b_k = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(kx) dx.
$$

Immediately, we get that $b_k=0$ for even $k$, and we find

$$
b_k = \frac{2 (\pi -\pi  \cos (\pi  k))}{\pi  \left(16 k-4 k^3\right)}
$$

which gives the same expansion as our initial sum.

I feel like there should be a way of converting this to the real Fourier series expansion to show convergence, however, I'm unable to figure out how.

---

Furthermore, I've tried to look at uniform convergence from the definition, but I haven't been able to make much progress as I don't know how to deal with the $\sin$ in the sum.

$$
\Bigg| \frac{\sin(x)}{3} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty - \frac{\sin((2n+3)x)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)(2n+5)}  - \frac{\pi}{8} \sin^2 (x) \Bigg| < \epsilon.
$$

---

Finally, I've looked at the problem numerically, and have been able to show that the series likely converges uniformly, and therefore also pointwise.

- [Wolfram Alpha link for pointwise convergence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2F3+-+sum_%28n%3D0%29%5E10+%28%28sin%28%282n%2B3%29x%29%29%2F%28%282n%2B1%29%282n%2B3%29%282n%2B5%29%29%29++-+pi%2F8+sin%5E2%28x%29%2C+x%3Dpi%2F2).
- [Wolfram Alpha link for uniform convergence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2F3+-+sum_%28n%3D0%29%5E5+%28%28sin%28%282n%2B3%29x%29%29%2F%28%282n%2B1%29%282n%2B3%29%282n%2B5%29%29%29++-+pi%2F8+sin%5E2%28x%29).

How would I be able to continue my analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without Fourier analysis.*
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\exp(i(2n+3)x)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)(2n+5)}=\frac{1}{12} \left(4 i \sin (x)+\cos (x)-6 \sin ^2(x) \tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i
   x}\right)\right) $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n+3)x)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)(2n+5)}=\frac{1}{12} \sin (x) \left(4-3 i \sin (x) \left(\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\tanh
   ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)\right)$$

Now, using
$$\tanh ^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$
$$\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(-i \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(i \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)=\frac 12 \log(-1)$$

Just continue using the appropriate branch for $\log (-1)$.

Comment: Thanks I can follow your argument except for the first part where you write the exponential sum in terms of elementary terms. Why can you write it that way?